# UiScrollable scroll to quick setting at WearOS

Tags: android, ui-automation, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have UiAutomator code for WearOS tests which uses scroller to find element

```
val scrollItem = UiSelector().text("Sensors")
val scroller = UiScrollable(UiSelector().scrollable(true))

scroller.scrollIntoView(scrollItem)
```

The issue is - for some reason it's open quick settings of Samsung Watch 4 and test fail, when in Pixel Watch it's working as intended.
I can make some workaround like this:

```
  repeat (20) {
      automatorDown()
      if(scrollItem) {
        reuturn@repeat}
    }
}
```

But it is just doesn't fill right.

Are there any ways to block scroller to open quick settings ?